Can I use k8s CRD status.condition[] to save some config
Can I use k8s CR status.condition[] to save some config
My CR Object status:
type MyCRStatus struct {
    OpType     string                `json:"opType,omitempty"`
    Status     State                 `json:"status,omitempty"`
    Message    string                `json:"message,omitempty"`
    Conditions []metav1.Condition    `json:"conditions,omitempty"`
}

When the state machine step is finished. One 'condition' will be added with the step result.
Can I use this kind of condition result to other place. for example, In other step, I get CR object, and check the condition result to decide following process?
func (r *ReconcileCRObject) Reconcile()
{
    obj := &test.CRObject{}
    err := r.Client.Get(ctx, req.NamespacedName, obj)
 
    if obj.Status.Conditions[0].Reason == "someresult" {
         // do something
    } else {
         // do else
    }
}


I'm not sure if this is possible, I've never seen code like this before.

I'd imagine the code you show would work.  Can you determine that (previous) state in some other way, though?  If the CR's spec: has some description of what it intends to produce, can you check reality against the expected final state, without recording persistent state in the CR?

Yes, i can, but I want to know whether 'status.condition' is also a kind of solutions. Thanks!:)
